# Is it possible to grant SUPER privileges to a user on a shared host?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am just trying to add a function to one of my tables, but I keep getting the error '''#1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)''' I definitely don't know tons about MySQL or PHPMyAdmin, but from other Google searches and such my understanding is that I need to set the global variable log_bin_trust_function_creators equal to 1, but I am unable to do that without SUPER privileges. I am currently on a shared Dreamhost hosting service, so is it possible to get SUPER privileges through a shared host? If no, is there a way to add functions without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to ask [Dreamhost support](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/218084068-Contacting-support-overview) about this.

It is technically possible to grant SUPER privilege to you. Alternatively, they could set the global variable for you without granting you that privilege. But in either case, it's up to them.

I doubt they will grant you SUPER privilege on a shared host. This would allow you to do all sorts of damage to their other customers' databases, even if unintentionally. If I were them, I would not grant this privilege to you.

But they might offer you an alternative to meet your need, such as moving your account to a dedicated server, so your application is the only one using that instance of MySQL. That will probably cost more for you, but if you really need to create a function, then that's what you have to do.

Comment: I assumed this was most likely going to be the answer... I will contact them and see if there is anything that can be done. Thanks!